# Html Image will not load under any change - Golang

Tags: html, css, image, go

I am trying to load an image locally onto my html. I first tried serving an image path through a **/images/** folder, but that did not work. I then tried serving images with the whole path to the image like `<img src="/Users/code/src/code/go/src/websites/website/website-Bucket.png" alt="test">` but I still had no luck. I checked my html and it has no errors. I have **restarted my P**C, changed the image to **.jpg**, and it still did not want to work. I get an error in Safari - **An error occurred while trying to load the resource** and the image shows as a blue box and question mark. What things would you try to troubleshoot?

Extra - I am using goLang to serve the files. I have it so a **http.handleFunc()** goes off and serves the images folder when it is requested. The path is showing **http://localhost/images/theImage.png** "the correct path" but nothing happens. So, I save the image and it shows it as a html and shows a section of the page?? Would that be a path thing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it may be a file path issue. 

Take a look at this page it has a good example.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Also try renaming the image with a _ and not use the -.

Comment: It should be correct. I am taking the exact file path and it still doesn't load.

Comment: The file path is in relation to where your html file is not the file path on your computer, etc.

Comment: here is a youtube video that might explain it better or at least a visual. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tg1ujA_TuDM

Answer (score 1):

In first instance you have to understand the path source, when you are on a HTML file, your path inside the file should be :

```
<img src="images/website-Bucket.png" alt="test">
```

that's because :
the path of your .html file can access trough files the inside path with the "/folder/file" structure route in the html file, so your structure files should be:

- yourfiel.html  (your file render on browser) /imagesfolder
- -website-Bucket.png"  (you call it on your html as
- /imagesfolder/website/Bucket.png)./

you can learn more about paths here :
http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: It is saying the path is localhost/images/image.png? Its correct but it still will not show? I download it and it shows image.png.html? Would that mean anything?

Comment: i mean, you have a index.html file in a folder , all that is in the sime level folder size of that html file should be aded with direct path call, example : if you have a index.html file inside folder "myFolder", all that is inside the "myfolder",  should called with absolute path 'code' <img src="image.png">'code', that's if you have in the same folder  level the image file, and the index.html file, if you have a folder "image" inside "myFolder", you should calle 'code' <img src="image/myimage.png">'code'

Comment: look at [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files

Comment: the path is 100% correct looking at all of these examples. I have moved it to every type of folder and it still will not work. It just shows the small little blue question mark. I right click and say open in a new tab and it loads my localhost page again?

Answer (score 1):

Open Console in any browser and see if you see any errors that mention not being able to find the source path of the picture.

It should give you a hint of where your browser is trying to find that img.

Answer (score 1):

All of your guy's responses were correct. I had the correct path. It was **a Golang thing**. I did not make a **handlefunc** when the server wants the **/image.png**. It was never serving the image, it just was doing nothing with it. Thank you for the responses.

Comment: thanks you too, try to change the subject to something more closed to Golang, so other people can access to the solution, greetings